# Exiting SSH sessions suddenly killing Apache

Tags: linux, ssh, apache-2.4

Okay, this is a doozy. I'm running Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 server instances. I use near-identical environments for both production and testing instances, as well as a near-identical VirtualBox instance that I manage using Vagrant for development. For the longest time, I've been able to SSH into any of these server instances as the same user that Apache runs under, deploy some application code changes, and then run `exit` to terminate the SSH session, and Apache would be running just fine afterward. Now, however, I can't do an `exit` without the Apache service encountering a fatal error:

```
[mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 23466] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[core:alert] [pid 17750] AH00050: Child 23466 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
```

Notes:

- The Apache user is `app`.
- If I SSH as `app`, switch to `root`, `restart` the service as `root`, switch back to `app`, then terminate the session, it kills Apache.
- If I SSH as `root`, `restart` the service, then terminate the session, Apache is fine.
- If I SSH as `root`, `restart` the service, switch to `app`, switch back to `root`, then terminate the session, Apache is fine.
- If I SSH as `root`, `restart` the service, terminate the session, SSH again as `app`, then terminate the session again, it kills Apache.
- Prior to this week, I've been able to consistently SSH as `app`, switch to `root`, `restart` the service as `root`, and terminate the session without killing Apache.
- I've tried modifying `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/apache2-systemd.conf` and changing the line `RemainAfterExit=no` to `RemainAfterExit=yes`, performed a `systemctl daemon-reload`, and finally a `service apache2 restart` with no effect.

Is there some explanation for the sudden change in behavior? Is there a reasonable fix to restore previous behavior? If not, then what would be best practice for deploying changes to application code and giving permissions for Apache (the `app` user) to read it without needing to log in to an SSH session as `root`? The entire reason for logging in as `app` was to limit the need to log in as `root` in the first place.

I'm at a complete loss here and don't understand how everything could suddenly be broken.

Comment: Did you try the solutions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652808/apache-shutdown-couldnt-grab-mutex

Comment: @tetech The `Mutex posixsem` solution seems to work, thanks! I'd still like to understand the solution rather than relying on a magic black box, however. I'm always nervous about unexplained fixes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The root cause of this is a change in how systemd (from 219) handles IPC objects created by logged in users. By default it will remove any IPC objects left after the user logs out. This applies to all non-system users (uid >= 1000). System users (uid < 1000) are not affected.

Since you have changed Apache to run under a non-system user, whenever you log out of that user account, systemd nukes all of Apache's IPC objects, and Apache then complains about losing its mutex and dies.

You can change this behavior by setting `RemoveIPC=no` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` (the default on Ubuntu is `yes`) and restarting `systemd-logind.service`.

It's better to leave Apache running as a system user (e.g. `www-data` on Ubuntu), and use permissions and ACLs to give `www-data` access to files it needs to read/write.

Comment: Interesting, this seems to also work. I'll definitely have to look into moving toward better understanding group permissions and integrating them into the permissions structure, but for now this is definitely catching my eye. My `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` showed a commented out line with `RemoveIPC=yes`, which seems to me to suggest that the `RemoveIPC=no` behavior wasn't originally the default. If so, then that would at least partially explain what happened, although I'm still confused as to why the behavior would suddenly change without any recent updates.

Comment: @B.Fleming Were there really no recent updates? Or were they just not restarted for a long time after some older updates? In any event, it's certainly possible to track down exactly which update brought in this change, but it won't really help solve the problem, so it may not be worth the effort. AFAIK it was in systemd 219, so perhaps Ubuntu was running a patch to change this default and removed it at some point.

Comment: I'm more interested in why something that worked suddenly broke, as that's always concerning to me. Having taken a look around, it appears that two days ago there was a `dpkg.log` entry showing `systemd` as installed. Although the version seems unchanged, it's possible that some form of automatic update occurred that either changed default behavior or modified the config file, but unfortunately I can only speculate. Either way, I feel that something of that nature makes the most sense in explaining what actually happened, and your info about `RemoveIPC` was the key. Your answer helped a ton :)

Comment: @B.Fleming "system" accounts (UID < 1000) are handled specially by many different programs in Linux, not just systemd. I recommend having Apache run as a system user, and logging in yourself as a non-system user. You can add yourself to the `www-user` *group* so that you can access the same files as Apache, and use the `chown` command to give apache access to files you create for it. `chown`, `chgrp` and `chmod` will become your friends --- as well as `ls -l`. :-)

Comment: @jpaugh Don't forget `setfacl`.

Comment: @jpaugh Setting up group permissions and reverting to the `www-data` user is definitely on the to-do list for sure, I can assure you of that. I'll just need to take the time to put some decent mechanisms in place for simplifying the management of server access for individual non-system users, which will take some time. I'm very familiar with handling user permissions, I just haven't successfully handled group permissions in the past, so I need to make sure I get it right. I appreciate the feedback nonetheless :)

Comment: @B.Fleming Note that you can [cause group permissions to propagate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12842/8503) to all files in a directory Thanks for your kind words.